# How to add a "..." after a particular word/character limit in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, string, split, strlen

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
    <p><?php echo the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
```

The above php code returns the following content:

```
absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna hssnnss hssns snnss nnshs sjjjjsjsj nsnnnsns jjsnss snsnns nsnns
```

What I want is, after a particular word limit it should display ... Lets say after 8 words it should be like this;

```
absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna...
```

I tried in the following way but it is showing all of the words:

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
<p><?php $out = strlen(the_title()) > 50 ? substr(the_title(),0,50)."..." : the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Relevant [wordpress.se] page: [Is there any difference between the_title() and echo get_the_title()?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/212012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`the_title()` echoes the title rather than returning it. If you're performing operations on it then you want to use `get_the_title()`.

```php
<div class="case-breaking__content">
<p><?php echo strlen(get_the_title()) > 50 ? substr(get_the_title(), 0, 50) . "..." : get_the_title(); ?></p>
</div>
```

That being said if you're using WordPress the easiest option is to use the built-in function `wp_trim_words()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words

So in your case

```php
<div class="case-breaking__content">
<p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 8, '...') ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You might simply do a `preg_split` on spaces, then join the array back to a string, with a limit number, if you wish:

```
$str = "absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna hssnnss hssns snnss nnshs sjjjjsjsj nsnnnsns jjsnss snsnns nsnns
";

$arr = preg_split('/(\s)/m', $str);
$limit = 8;
$title = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if ($key < $limit) {
        $title .= $value . " ";
    } else {
        $title .= "...";
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($title);
```

#### Output

```
string(47) "absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna ..."
```

You might also add an `if` statement, in case the number of words was less than your desired limit, so that to just break the loop, maybe something similar to:

```
$str = "absv shss xcnx shss hshhs";
// $str = "absv shss xcnx shss hshhs shhsw shshs hsnna hssnnss hssns snnss nnshs sjjjjsjsj nsnnnsns jjsnss snsnns nsnns";

$arr = preg_split('/(\s)/m', $str);
$limit = 8;
$title = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (sizeof($arr) < $limit - 1) {
        $title .= $str . " ...";
        break;
    }
    if ($key < $limit) {
        $title .= $value . " ";
    } else {
        $title .= "...";
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($title);
```

#### Output

```
string(29) "absv shss xcnx shss hshhs ..."
```

#### Implement

If you wish to implement this code, this might work:

```
$arr = preg_split('/(\s)/m', get_the_title());
$limit = 8; // number of words limit
$title = '';
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (sizeof($arr) < $limit - 1) {
        $title .= get_the_title() . " ...";
        break;
    }
    if ($key < $limit) {
        $title .= $value . " ";
    } else {
        $title .= "...";
        break;
    }
}

$out = '<div class="case-breaking__content">';
$out .= '<p>';
$out .= $title;
$out .= '</p>';
$out .= '</div>';

echo $out;
```

Comment: The capturing parentheses around `\s` provide no benefit.  Not using `+` after `\s` risks counting "phantom words" (empty strings) if two or more spaces occur consecutively.  The `m` pattern is useless because there are no anchors in the pattern (e.g. `^` or `$`).  This solution adds three dots when it is not necessary (no string truncation was called for) Proof: https://3v4l.org/DOYXm

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="case-breaking__content">
    <?php $words = explode(" ", the_title()); ?>
    <p><?php echo count($words) <= 8 ? the_title() : implode(" ", array_slice($words, 0, 8)) . "..."; ?></p>
</div>
```

Vanilla PHP solution, doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: FYI, the default behavior of `the_title()` will `echo` the title.  It is probably better to call `get_the_title()` instead.  Please see my answer.  Your answer would be better if you added some explanation of how your code works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use WordPress, but its [source code for `wp_trim_words()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/5.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3874-L3917) looks more cumbersome than I like.

The default behavior of `the_title()` is to `echo` the string.  In this case, you will want to `return` the string so that it can be mutated before it is echoed. This is accomplished by setting its 3rd parameter to `false`. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

Or more simply call [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

To conditionally apply a word limit, a single `preg_replace()` call will suffice.

Logically, it makes no sense to add the ellipsis unless the word limit is exceeded, my pattern below checks for 8 sets of zero or more whitespaces followed by one or more non-whitespaces.  If there are 8 "words" AND at least one character to remove, then `\K` "forgets" the previously matched 8 words, then replaces the remainder of the input string with three dots.

Code: ([Demo with hardcoded sample strings](https://3v4l.org/vJuo6))

```
$wordLimit = 8;
echo preg_replace('/(?:\s*\S++){' . $wordLimit . '}\K.+/', '...', get_the_title());
```

`\S++` the possessive one-or-more quantifier forces greedy matching of non-whitespace characters -- this ensures that *all* of the final word is matched.